# Suspending Other Threads when A thread Starts Vb.Net

Tags: vb.net, multithreading

I am working on a utility which scans a user defined directory and extracts all the file extensions.
In the below mentioned button event, i am starting thread in which all the scanning is done but i want the code to suspend or stop at 'Point A' till that thread completes its work whereas now it starts the thread and continue after the 'Point A'. How to stop the code to continue?

```
Private Sub Btn_Extract_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Btn_Extract.Click
    Dim eventobject As New EventsandFunctions
    eventobject.FilesCounter = 0
    eventobject.DirectoryCounter = 0
    AddHandler eventobject.FilesScanned, AddressOf eventobject.FilesScannedCounterIncrease
    AddHandler eventobject.DirectoryScanned, AddressOf eventobject.DirectoryScannedCounterIncrease
    If TxtB_SaveFilePath.Text = Nothing Or TxtBx_DirectoryToScan.Text = Nothing Then
        MessageBox.Show("Scan Path, Output File Path or Both Missing", "Error")
    Else

        ThreadFileScanning.Start(eventobject) 'Thread Starts here--<Point A>
        If ChckB_RemoveDot.Checked Then
            eventobject.WriteExtentionsToFileWithoutDot(TxtB_SaveFilePath.Text)
        Else
            eventobject.WriteExtentionsToFile(TxtB_SaveFilePath.Text)
        End If
        MessageBox.Show("Operation Completed Successfully." & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Total Directory Scanned: " & eventobject.DirectoryCounter & vbCrLf & "Total Files Scanned: " & eventobject.FilesCounter, "Completion Notification")
        Lbl_FileNames.Text = "Scanning & Writing Completed"
    End If
    Process.Start("notepad.exe", TxtB_SaveFilePath.Text)

End Sub
```

Following is the Function which is called in the thread:

```
Public Sub RecursivelyScanFiles(ByVal Path As String, ByVal ObjectDb As DialogueBox)

    If Path <> Nothing Then
        For Each File In GetFiles(Path)
            If File.Length < 260 Then
                If System.IO.Path.HasExtension(File) = True Then
                    Extentions.Add(System.IO.Path.GetExtension(File).ToLower)
                End If
                ObjectDb.settext(File) 'Cross-Thread call Through a Delegate
                ObjectDb.Refreshlabel() 'Cross-Thread call Through a Delegate
                RaiseEvent FilesScanned(Me, EventArgs.Empty)
            End If
        Next
    End If
    If Path <> Nothing Then
        For Each SubDir In GetDirectories(Path)
            If SubDir.Length < 248 Then
                Try
                    RaiseEvent DirectoryScanned(Me, EventArgs.Empty)
                    RecursivelyWriteToFile(SubDir, ObjectDb)
                Catch ex As UnauthorizedAccessException
                    Continue For
                Catch ex As Exception
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString)
                End Try
            End If
        Next
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: You are asking the wrong question, the code has too many problems to take a stab at an answer.  Use the BackgroundWorker class to avoid making the most basic mistakes, its RunWorkerCompleted and ProgressChanged events help you fall in the pit of success.

Comment: I read about BackgroundWorker on MSDN but i thought using delegates is more easy. Do you suggest BackgroundWorker?

Comment: I agree with @HansPassant. Where possible, a Background worker should be used, but as the question was for threads, I've given an answer that should work with threads (if I understand the question correctly)

Comment: If Thread A is going to start Thread B and then wait until Thread B finishes before continuing, then you have gained no benefit from using a second thread. Just have Thread A do the work.

Comment: @JimMischel, I agree with you, but there may be times you are working on a non UI thread, and need to do some work on the UI thread that requires you to wait (just to use a weak example, lol)

Comment: No, its a UI thread, and Jim pointed out very good thing, Let me restructure my code and then i will come back here to repost. Thanks everyone. :)

Comment: @Rehan, just be aware of adding code to the UI thread that will take time to complete, as this will freeze up your program. In that case, its best to use a background worker...

Comment: @Grahamvs Yup, that was the problem i faced then i made threads. :)

Answer (score 0):

Create a global boolean (`isBusy`), and set it to `True` when the thread starts, then set it as `False` when the thread is done, like so:

```
Private isBusy as Boolean = False

Private Sub Btn_Extract_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Btn_Extract.Click

    ' Other code goes here

    ThreadFileScanning.Start(eventobject) 'Thread Starts here--<Point A>

    ' This will prevent the thread from continuing 
    ' while the ThreadFileScanning is busy
    While isBusy
        Threading.Thread.Sleep(200)
    End While

    If ChckB_RemoveDot.Checked Then
        eventobject.WriteExtentionsToFileWithoutDot(TxtB_SaveFilePath.Text)
    Else
        eventobject.WriteExtentionsToFile(TxtB_SaveFilePath.Text)
    End If

    ' rest of the code goes here

End Sub

Public Sub RecursivelyScanFiles(ByVal Path As String, ByVal ObjectDb As DialogueBox)
    isBusy = True

    ' Rest of code goes here

    isBusy = False
End Sub
```

This will prevent the first thread from continuing while `RecursivelyScanFiles` is active.

Comment: Good Idea!! :) but i think Hans is more experienced than us two and he is suggesting something else.

Comment: Busy waiting is a rather bad idea. There's already a way to wait for a thread to complete: `Thread.Join`. Or you could use an `EventWaitHandle` of some sort. A `Sleep` loop with a `Boolean` flag is a really terrible idea.

Comment: It's just a basic idea to get him started... Since it's on he UI thread, you could adjust the time accordingly, and use an `application.DoEvents` (and yes, I know some people don't like using this) to keep the program responsive, and perhaps show a progressbar set to continuous, so the user knows it hasn't frozen